# Calling function from hook not working as expected

Tags: hooks

I am trying to add a hook which calls `shr-render-buffer` after loading a file in `html-mode`. This is what I came up with:

`(add-hook 'html-mode-hook (lambda () (call-interactively #'shr-render-buffer)))`

This works, except not quite as expected.

Calling `M-x shr-render-buffer` in an `html-mode` buffer splits the current frame vertically, and puts the rendered output in the bottom window with the html still visible in the top window. On the other hand, if I do `find-file` and open an html file, my hook code splits the frame vertically, but buries the html buffer, so that I have the rendered buffer on the bottom, and whichever buffer I was visiting when I did `find-file` at the top.

What is happening here? Seemingly, something with the timing is getting messed up from the way I am calling `shr-render-buffer`, but I don't really know what/how.

Comment: It is not clear what the question is. You say "This works, except not quite as expected." Do you mind specifying *what* exactly is expected, i.e. the behavior you are trying to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: In your hook function, you can try call `(call-interactively #'she-render-buffer)` with a slight delay by using `run-at-time`, e.g., `(run-at-time 0.1 nil (lambda () (call-interactively #'shr-render-buffer)))`, to simulate a manual  invocation.

Comment: This is not related to hooks at all, rather using functions which are meant to be used interactively in a programmatic way.  If you check the sources of `shr-render-buffer`, you'll see that it uses `pop-to-buffer` to show you a `*html*` buffer.  How exactly that happens depends on a number of unknowns as specified by the many `display-buffer`-related variables.

Comment: @Constantine: see the paragraph right after that statement. I was hoping that it would work the way `shr-render-buffer` does when called interactively. However, I gather from @wasamasa  's comment that this is less straightforward than I thought. I will try @xuchunyang's solution to see if that helps.

Comment: How about(?):  Create a new function that just returns the `*html*` buffer `my-shr-noselect-buf` -- without displaying it.  Then, have your four (4) favorite functions on stand-by for just such an occasion.  Decide which direction you want to display your buffer (left/right/up/down), and then create another function with just one line -- e.g., `my-html-display-buffer-left` which calls `(my-display-buffer-left (my-shr-noselect-buf))` and and that to the hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) `shr-render-current-buffer-noselect` creates an HTML rendering of the current-buffer, but does not select or display said rendering in any particular window.  The value returned is the HTML buffer.

(2) `my-display-buffer` is a little complex in terms of its capabilities that are dependent upon the built-in library `window.el`, which is beyond the scope of this example.  For purposes of this example, let us just focus on the third argument DIRECTION -- either `'left`, `'right`, `'above`, or `'below`.  Essentially, there are three built-in options -- **(a)** if the window already displaying the target buffer exists, then that will become the target window; **(b)** if there is already a window in the desired direction, then it will be used as the target window; **(c)** the catch-all is to create a new window in the desired direction if (a) and (b) are not applicable.

(3) `my-shr-display-buffer` uses a direction of `'right` in this example (see above).

(4) The hook.

```lisp
(require 'shr)

(defun shr-render-current-buffer-noselect ()
"Generate (but do not select) an HTML rendering of the current buffer."
  (or (fboundp 'libxml-parse-html-region)
      (error "This function requires Emacs to be compiled with libxml2"))
  (let* (
      (htmlbuf (get-buffer-create "*html*"))
      (dom (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))) )
    (with-current-buffer htmlbuf
      (erase-buffer)
      (shr-insert-document dom)
      (goto-char (point-min)))
    htmlbuf))

(defun my-display-buffer (buffer alist direction &optional size pixelwise)
"BUFFER:  The buffer that will be displayed.
ALIST:  See the doc-string of `display-buffer' for more information.
DIRECTION:  Must use one of these symbols:  'left 'right 'below 'above
SIZE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
PIXELWISE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'"
  (let (
      (window
        (cond
          ((get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)))
          ((window-in-direction direction))
          (t
            (split-window (selected-window) size direction pixelwise)))))
    (window--display-buffer buffer window 'window alist display-buffer-mark-dedicated)
    window))

(defun my-shr-display-buffer ()
  (let ((buffer (shr-render-current-buffer-noselect)))
    (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'right nil nil)))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'my-shr-display-buffer)
```